# Git no me sube los ficheros nuevos al repositorio de mi proyecto en GitHub

Tags: git, github

Estoy intentando actualizar mi proyecto de gitHub con unos fichero que añadi recientemente desde uno de mis ordenadores. El caso es el siguiente:

Tengo **29 ficheros** en mi cuenta de **GitHub** .

En mi pc añadi **1 fichero mas**.

Por tanto mi ordenador tengo **30 ficheros** y en GitHub tengo **29 ficheros**.

He estado intentado subir lese nuevo fichero yendome al directorio de mi pc donde tengo todo actualizado y ejecuto los siguientes comandos con **GitBash** :

```
 git add .
```

Luego ejecuto en comando `git status` para ver que va a ser cambiado y me dice :

> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Finalmente ejecuto el comando **commit -m 'comentario'** y me arroja el mismo mensaje:

> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Por tanto comando **git push origin master** tampoco funciona pues no puede subir nada.

Mi **pregunta** es : ¿Por que no me detecta que tengo un fichero mas en mi PC y lo sube a mi repositorio de gitHub?

Comment: Sin más detalles no lo puedo asegurar, pero es posible que tengas un fichero llamado `.gitignore` entre los 29, que incluya el nombre del que quieres añadir. Ese fichero es la lista de elementos a ignorar por git y GitHub suele crearlo por defecto

Comment: creo que es porque con el "git add ." ya estar agregando los cambios para hacer el commit, por eso no te dice que tengas cambios. Prueba haciendo un cambio a algún archivo, después ejecuta "git status" y te debería mostrar información, después "git" add ." para agregar todos los cambios y finalizas con "git comit -m "Mensaje".

Comment: has git status eso te dira que archivos tienes para commit

Comment: y luegom git push

Answer (score 3):

Usa el comando git add -A (a por all) esto deberia incluir todos los archivos nuevos del proyecto.

usar force no creo que sea recomendable ya que no es ese su proposito.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion, use la propiedad `--force` en el `push` quedando de la siguiente manera :

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: Por lo general creo que no es recomendable utilizar `--force`; como el mismo nombre lo dice, estas *forzando* una accion; solo para que lo tengas en mente

Answer (score -3):

Si es una carpeta, añade algo en su interior, no la dejes vacía, por defecto deberíamos agregar README.md

Comment: Hola Miguel, no es necesario agregar un archivo README.md